# Parsing a string to get a specific value

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I'm parsing for a lot number in a 2D barcode. The actual lot number 'A2351' is hidden in this barcode string "+M727PP011/$$3201001A2351S". I would like to break this barcode up in separate string blocks but the delimiters are not consistent.

The letter prefix in front of the 4 digit lot number can be a 'A', 'P', or a 'D' There is a single letter following the lot number that can be ignored.

```
string Delimiter = "/$$3"; 

//barcode format:M###PP###/$$3  ddmmyy lotnumprefix 'A' followed by lotNum    
string lotNum= "+M727PP011/$$3201001A2351S";  

string[] split = lotNum.Split(new[] {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

How do I extract the lot number after the date?

Comment: It looks like (from your format comment) that the string is always a consistent length up until the `A`, so why not just take a substring from that point?

Comment: if the lot number always starts with an A, perhaps you can look for that and try and take the values after?

Comment: Contact the person responsible for sending you the barcode and ask how to extract the lot number.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your initial example and then the subsequent edit in which you showed how you are solving this, it sounds like the lot number is always in the same place.  It would be cleaner (and more in line with standard C# code) to use a single call to [string.Substring(int,int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than the two lines you are using which also require pulling in the VB library. You just need to call `Substring` and give it the starting index and the length.

So this code:

```
string lotNum = Strings.Right(barcode, 6);
lotNum = lotNum.Remove((lotNum.Length - 1), 1);
```

Can be done with this single substring call:

```
string lotNum = barcode.Substring(barcode.Length - 6, 5);
```

**Edit**
Just further clarification on why it might be better to use the call to `Substring`. In C# `string` objects are immutable.  That means that when you make the call to `Strings.Right` you are getting back a new string object.  When you then call `lotNum.Remove` you do not "remove" a character from the existing string, a new string is allocated with the character(s) removed and is returned to you.  So with your code there are two new string allocations when trying to extract the lot number.  When you make the call to `Substring` you will get back a new string, but instead of getting a new string that you immediately then modify and get a second new string, you will only need to allocate one new string to extract the lot number.  In the example you have given there probably would not be any noticeable performance/memory issue, but it is something that could potentially lead to trouble if this code was in a tight loop or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the lot number, it's really dependent on the format of the input string (is it a consistent length, are there any reliable prefixes/suffixes relative to the data you're trying to parse that you can reference from, etc). It looks like your data is definable by its static position in the string, so it looks like you could use the [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) 
 (with an index of 20?) method to accomplish what you want.